# why is my form.is_valid() always returning false?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

So the problem is that when i call the two methods authorSearch and deleteAuthor in views.py, form,is_valid() is always returning false.

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.author_name
```

Forms.py

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Author
            fields = ['author_name',]
```

views.py

```
def authorSearch(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
            form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                  #some processing here
                  return render(request,'authorSearch.html',{})
            else:
                    return HttpResponse('No such Author Found!')
    else:
            form = AuthorForm()
            return render(request,'authorSearch.html',{'form':form})

def deleteAuthor(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
            form=AuthorForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    #some processing here
                    return HttpResponse('Author deleted successfully!')
            else:
                    return HttpResponse('Author deletetion failed!')
    else:
            form=AuthorForm()
            return render(request,'deleteAuthor.html',{'form':form})
```

authorSearch.html

```
<div class='container'>
{% if request.method == 'GET' %}
     <form action='' method='POST'>
          <!--Some html here -->
     </form>
{% elif request.method == 'POST' %}
    <!--Some html here -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are yous submitting your forms with empty fields?

Comment: No!! of course not. I am filling the form with the exact name of the author as it should be.

Comment: I am guessing the problem is somewhere that i made a string(author_name) the primary key which also includes spaced characters and everything...so maybe when it is comparing that in views.py it fails due to some reason.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess: you forgot the csrf token.

Simply print the actual data sent to the form and the errors to see what's happening !

```
def authorSearch(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
              #some processing here
             return render(request,'authorSearch.html',{})
        else:
             # you want to check what's happening here
             # something like this (from memory, might be wrong):
             print request.POST
             print form.errors
             print form.non_field_errors

             return HttpResponse('No such Author Found!')
    else:
        form = AuthorForm()
        return render(request,'authorSearch.html',{'form':form})
```

---

Also, I'd personally recommend you to:

- use `Charles` or something similar to check the HTTP requests and responses
- write tests :)

Comment: i tried form.errors and it says author with this author name already exists...is it trying to add the author??..because I used Author.objects.get() to get the object and then I am deleting it with .delete() method. So this error should not have been there.

Comment: <bound method AuthorForm.non_field_errors of <AuthorForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(author_name)>>

on using form.non_field_errors i get this message. I think its saying that the field is not correct..but it really is.

Comment: @AkashTomar Oh yeah you've put `primary_key=True` so that field must be unique.

Comment: yes it is unique....anyways django will not accept the same author again. The problem is something else.